# JFreeChart interpolate values

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have a `JFreeChart` TimeSeriesChart where some of the values may contain nulls, because they only exist if they change above a certain threshold.

[image: Chart]

Is there a way to tell it to ignore values which are null, and connect (interpolate) in between?

The code is here:

```
final TimeSeries tseries = new TimeSeries("Temperature");
final TimeSeries hseries = new TimeSeries("Humidity");
final TimeSeries pseries = new TimeSeries("Pressure");

for (final Map<String, Object> value : list) {
    final Date datetime = (Date) value.get("datetime");
    final BigDecimal temperature = (BigDecimal) value.get("temperature");
    final BigDecimal humidity = (BigDecimal) value.get("humidity");
    final BigDecimal pressure = (BigDecimal) value.get("pressure");
    tseries.add(new Millisecond(datetime), temperature);
    hseries.add(new Millisecond(datetime), humidity);
    pseries.add(new Millisecond(datetime), pressure);
}

final JFreeChart timeChart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(sensor.getName(), null, null, null, false, false, false);

timeChart.getXYPlot().setRangeAxis(new NumberAxis("Temperature (°C)"));
timeChart.getXYPlot().getRangeAxis().setRange(-10, 30);
((NumberAxis) timeChart.getXYPlot().getRangeAxis()).setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(5));

timeChart.getXYPlot().setDataset(0, new TimeSeriesCollection(tseries));
timeChart.getXYPlot().setDataset(1, new TimeSeriesCollection(hseries));
timeChart.getXYPlot().setDataset(2, new TimeSeriesCollection(pseries));

timeChart.getXYPlot().setRenderer(0, new StandardXYItemRenderer());
timeChart.getXYPlot().setRenderer(1, new StandardXYItemRenderer());
timeChart.getXYPlot().setRenderer(2, new StandardXYItemRenderer());

final NumberAxis humAxis = new NumberAxis("Humidity (%)");
humAxis.setRange(20, 80);
humAxis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(5));
timeChart.getXYPlot().setRangeAxis(1, humAxis);
timeChart.getXYPlot().mapDatasetToRangeAxis(1, 1);

final NumberAxis pressAxis = new NumberAxis("Pressure (hPa)");
pressAxis.setRange(970, 1020);
pressAxis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(10));
timeChart.getXYPlot().setRangeAxis(2, pressAxis);
timeChart.getXYPlot().mapDatasetToRangeAxis(2, 2);

final DateAxis axis = (DateAxis) timeChart.getXYPlot().getDomainAxis();
scheduledReportService.setChartScale(scheduledReport, axis);

ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(baos, timeChart, Chart.WIDTH, Chart.HEIGHT);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because [`ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#createTimeSeriesChart-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset-boolean-boolean-boolean-) instantiates [`XYLineAndShapeRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYLineAndShapeRenderer.html), try [`setDrawSeriesLineAsPath()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYLineAndShapeRenderer.html#setDrawSeriesLineAsPath-boolean-):

```
XYPlot plot = timeChart.getXYPlot();
XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = (XYLineAndShapeRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
renderer.setDrawSeriesLineAsPath(true);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work, it makes no difference. Even setting setDrawSeriesLineAsPath() to true or false makes no change.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] with representative data that exhibits the problem you describe. Can you get the missing data from the source? If not, you may have to restore them as you `add()` values.

Comment: hi @yglodt , did you find a way to interpolate at the end? I am trying to solve the exact same problem.

Comment: Hi @Francesco, I believe I changed the data query behind to return data without gaps, so I solved it outside of JFreeChart

Comment: thanks @yglodt , maybe that's the right way, or interpolate with another library, as jfreechart is a chart library not an interpolation library at the end :) thanks for your quick answer

Comment: @Francesco's point is well taken; see also these related [discusstions](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/discussions?discussions_q=is%3Aopen+missing+data+).